# Get just one pixel value without allocating whole array of pixels

Tags: java, image

I just need to check three pixel values on the whole image (Image instance). I'd really like to do this without allocating an array of pixels.

Is that possible? Something like `BufferedImage`'s `getRGB()`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You are on the right track with the `getRGB` method, as it would return a single int with three values (RGB). To convert the single int to three ints, you can do two things:

**1.** Use the `Color` class's built-in constructor:

```
int rgb = img.getGraphics().getRGB(0,0);//Get color of pixel 0,0
Color c = new Color(rgb); //c now contains the r, g, and b values.
```

**2.** Build the decoder yourself:

```
int rgb = img.getGraphics().getRGB(0,0) //Get color of pixel 0,0
int r = rgb >> 24;
int g = 0 >> 16;
int b = 0 >> 8;
```

Both methods will return a `r`, `g`, and `b` value, which can be used.

Comment: The problem is that interface `Image` does not define `getRGB` method.